# C#: An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm running with VS-2013 Ultimate. While executing my code, I'm getting this error message box:

```
An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension
```

When entering the log file (the path is mentioned on the message), I'm get this exception:

```
  <entry>
    <record>905</record>
    <time>2014/08/22 15:46:25.494</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>
        System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.UI.ThreadMarkerGenerator.LocationMatchesTagger(DocumentContext location, MarkerTagger tagger)&#x000D;&#x000A;
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.UI.ThreadMarkerGenerator.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;GetMarkersForTagger&gt;b__0(ThreadMarker marker)&#x000D;&#x000A;
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.Extension.MarkerTagger.&lt;GenerateTagList&gt;d__a.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;
            at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)&#x000D;&#x000A;
            at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)&#x000D;&#x000A;
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.Extension.MarkerTagger..ctor(ITextBuffer buffer, ITextDocument document)&#x000D;&#x000A;
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.Extension.MarkerTaggerProvider.CreateTagger[T](ITextBuffer buffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)
        </description>
  </entry>
```

I'm sure that this code already worked well in the past.
What could be the reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: It's an exception in Visual Studio and has nothing to do with your code, unless you are debugging an Extension...

Comment: It's telling you there's a problem with an extension.. Are you sure it's your code?

Comment: Your error is not related to visual studio 2013. Debug your code after learning what a nullpointer exception is from the other responses.

Comment: Well what's the code that's throwing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the latest update of VS.

[Visual Studio exception thrown in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.dll in very rare circumstance](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797693/visual-studio-exception-thrown-in-microsoft-visualstudio-debugger-parallel-dll-in-very-rare-circumstance)

> We are happy to let you know that this issue has been fixed in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

Comment: I'm upgraded to VS2013 update3 and now it's working good! thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Fixed that problem by deleting the following folder:

> C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio{version-number}\ComponentModelCache

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with Visual Studio 2017.  I tried the above steps but still got the popup along with the windows sound.  Also, some of my (limited) extensions would not work (e.g. add new file, shift F2).

I found out that the temp folder was so full that Visual Studio has problems in creating temp files.

Solution:  Delete everything here ->

C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local

I had 5 GB of stuff here and Visual Studio started to run smoothly after a restart.